# How can I deploy a project using business central?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, drools, redhat-brms

I'm trying to deploy a project created in business central. Currently I'm using docker's jboss/drools-workbench container, and whenever I click on the deploy button I get an error message (see below).

I have looked at the server log and there was no error when attempting to deploy the project. I have also tried using standalone wildfly's management console to deploy Drools warfile which was unsuccessful since an error about missing/unavailable module (slf4j) and, in another instance, attempted to link to jboss/kie-server container with my drools-workbench container for which the application becomes unresponsive.

My rule is a simple "hello" application

```
rule "hello"
when
  $name: String( )
then
  System.out.println( "Hello " + $name + "!" );
end
```

And I also have tried linking jboss/kie-server container to drools-workbench container,

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name drools-workbench jboss/drools-workbench
$ docker run -p 8180:8080 -d --name kie-server --link drools-workbench:kie-wb jboss/kie-server
```

The server logs are in https://pastebin.com/A97exiJu the error I get from the UI is "Deployment was skipped, couldn't find any server running in 'development' mode." I have tried changing the project to production mode, but I still get the same error except for "development" it states "production".

Comment: Do you have the kie-server configured and running? I didn't find any kie-server deployed in the server logs shared.

Comment: I found out that jboss/jbpm-server-full is what I was looking for. And yes I was missing a kie-server.

Comment: For rules project deployment with kie server and business central, sample docker compose using showcase images [here](https://github.com/danial-k/drools-intro)